# Unable to install GCC using miniconda in Win10

Tags: anaconda

I am trying to install gcc before installing fbprophet.

I tried below two ways and it didn't work.  Thanks for your help.

1. conda install gcc
2. conda install -c conda-forge gcc

https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/gcc

The error is:

```
(forecast) C:\Users>conda install -c conda-forge gcc
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - gcc

Current channels:

  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.
```

Answer (score 2):

ok, i found the answer:

https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/m2w64-gcc-libs

```
conda install -c conda-forge m2w64-gcc-libs
```

Comment: I think you would need the `m2w64-gcc` package instead. That will install `m2w64-gcc-libs` and other - likely needed - packages as well.